# Do calculation with numbers with more than 16 digits which also can contain Decimal point(.)

Tags: ios, objective-c, primitive, primitive-types

I am making app which often need to do calculation with more than 16 digits which can also contain decimal point.

i.e. 9999999999999.99991234 * 58.15.

So, my question is which primitive i need to use?
I have tried with Double but It gives me wrong result after numbers like(12345678, 999999).
Another question is how to convert String(@"9999999999") to `Long Double`. like we can do FloatValue, DoubleValue, LonglongValue.

Is `long Double` is my solution?

Pardon me if any conceptual mistake, but i want to understand it.

Comment: You can check out NSDecimalNumber, it's not primitive value but it's good solution if you have to work with very precise floating points. [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/nsdecimalnumber_class/reference/reference.html)

Comment: @Greg , It's Inherited from NSNumber(An Object), So how can i do Arithmetics with it?

Comment: You have a methods to do the operations, for example: decimalNumberByAdding:

Comment: @Greg ,Thanks!! I am Going to try it now.